# module.export = mongoose.model('User', new Scheme({ ReferenceError: Scheme is not defined - nodejs issue

Tags: node.js, nodes

I'm new to **node.js**. I was trying to run the code from the link **https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens**. When I tried to run the server.js. The following error was coming:

```
E:\Eclipse IDE\Enide-Studio-2014.17-luna-SR1-win64-20141011\Enide-Studio-2014.17-luna-SR1-win64\ws\node-token-jwt\app\models\user.js:7
module.export = mongoose.model('User', new Scheme({
                                           ^
ReferenceError: Scheme is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Eclipse IDE\Enide-Studio-2014.17-luna-SR1-win64-20141011\Enide-Studio-2014.17-luna-SR1-win64\ws\node-token-jwt\app\models\user.js:7:44)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Eclipse IDE\Enide-Studio-2014.17-luna-SR1-win64-20141011\Enide-Studio-2014.17-luna-SR1-win64\ws\node-token-jwt\server.js:12:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

Please help me !

Also see attached of project structure.

[image]

**server.js**

```
// =======================
// get the packages we need ============
// =======================
var express     = require('express');
var app         = express();
var bodyParser  = require('body-parser');
var morgan      = require('morgan');
var mongoose    = require('mongoose');

var jwt    = require('jsonwebtoken'); // used to create, sign, and verify tokens
var config = require('./config'); // get our config file
var User   = require('./app/models/user'); // get our mongoose model

// =======================
// configuration =========
// =======================
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080; // used to create, sign, and verify tokens
mongoose.connect(config.database); // connect to database
app.set('superSecret', config.secret); // secret variable

// use body parser so we can get info from POST and/or URL parameters
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// use morgan to log requests to the console
app.use(morgan('dev'));

// =======================
// routes ================
// =======================
// basic route
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello! The API is at http://localhost:' + port + '/api');
});

// API ROUTES -------------------
// we'll get to these in a second

// =======================
// start the server ======
// =======================
app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens at http://localhost:' + port);
```

**user.js**

```
// get an instance of mongoose and mongoose.Schema
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//set up a mongoose model and pass it using module.exports
module.export = mongoose.model('User', new Scheme({
    name : String,
    password : String,
    admin : Boolean
}));
```

**EDIT-1**: I can see the new issue now:

```
C:\Users\workspace-nod\node-token-jwt\node_modules\mongodb\lib\server.js:242
        process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                      ^
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND noder noder:27017
    at errnoException (dns.js:27:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:78:26)
```

Please guide on this.

Comment: It should be `Schema` not `Scheme` no?

Comment: as devonJs suggested please correct spelling of Scheme to Schema than try again if still facing the problem than please let me know.

Comment: Thanks its working now, But I see new errors now..